# Rails HABTM query -- Article with ALL tags

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I created two tables in my app (Rails 3):

```
def change
  create_table :articles do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.text :content
    t.timestamps
  end

  create_table :tags do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.timestamps
  end

  create_table :articles_tags do |t|
    t.belongs_to :article
    t.belongs_to :tag
  end

  add_index :articles_tags, :article_id
  add_index :articles_tags, :tag_id
end
```

I want to be able to search for articles based on tags in two ways:

1. Articles with ANY of the given tags (**union**)
2. Articles with ALL of the given tags (**intersection**)

So, in other words, something that allows me to do this this:

```
tag1 = Tag.create(name: 'tag1')
tag2 = Tag.create(name: 'tag2')

a = Article.create; a.tags << tag1
b = Article.create; b.tags += [tag1, tag2]

Article.tagged_with_any(['tag1', 'tag2'])
# => [a,b]

Article.tagged_with_all(['tag1', 'tag2'])
# => [b]
```

The first one was relatively easy. I just made this scope on Article:

```
scope :tagged_with_any, lambda { |tag_names|
  joins(:tags).where('tags.name IN (?)', tag_names)
}
```

The problem is the second. I have no idea how to do this, in ActiveRecord or SQL.

I figure that I might be able to do something icky like this:

```
scope :tagged_with_all, lambda { |tag_names|
  new_scope = self

  # Want to allow for single string query args
  Array(tag_names).each do |name|
    new_scope = new_scope.tagged_with_any(name)
  end
  new_scope
}
```

but I'm betting that's crazy inefficient, and it just smells. Any ideas about how to do this correctly?

Comment: Ended up deciding this one one of many cases where homebrewing a solution to this wouldn't work as nicely as I liked. So I just installed [this gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on), which does some pretty neat stuff and looks pleasant to work with. Sort of a cop-out, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, that scope is crazy inefficient (and ugly).

Try with something like this:

```
def self.tagged_with_all(tags)
  joins(:tags).where('tags.name IN (?)', tags).group('article_id').having('count(*)=?', tags.count).select('article_id')
end
```

The key is in the `having` clause. You may also want to have a look at the SQL division operation between tables.

Comment: Thanks! That's some cool SQL stuff I haven't seen before. It doesn't seem to work in this case, though, as the Tag table doesn't have an article_id column. There's a join table ArticleTags that has article_id and tag_id, but I can't seem to get at it directly. Also, wouldn't that look for all Articles with any of the tags and exactly as many tags as were searched for? So if there are more it wouldn't find them, and if it has one of the tags but otherwise different ones it would?

Comment: The basic idea is: Join the article with the tags, but only with the Tags which have the specified names. Then, group the join results by article_id and if that group has equals size to the specified tags that means the article contains all the tags. Start by writing the sql in the postgres sql console and write the ruby code when the query works.